# What are the root and aboveground dimensions of a cotton plant at its largest?

Tags: farming, agriculture

I'm experimenting with optimal cotton growing techniques using the least amount of water required and plan on growing a cotton plant in simulated field conditions.

That said, I need a large enough pot that would allow the roots of the plant to grow unrestricted and was wondering: what is are the dimensions of a cotton plant at its largest, including the roots?

Comment: This question would get more answers on the Stack Exchange site for gardening.